# How can we get the year wise total rows count in a database of all tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a requirement to get the year wise tables total row count from a database. For example , if I have a database 'Adventures2008' which has 100 tables.In which only few tables had a column '[ModifiedTimeStamp]'. Now I want to get the dataset as below format
[image]

The column '[ModifiedTimeStamp]' is not present in few of the tables. So I need a SQL query to get the required output.I have tried many ways to but i'm unable to loop the tables with column 'ModifiedTimeStamp'.

Could anyone help me on this ?

Please let me know if any concerns/questions.

Comment: you have enough reputation to know what a post should contain..please modify accordingly.

Comment: Totally unclear.   What does "ModifiedTimeStamp" have to do with your desired output?   Where did "Student", "StudentGrade" and "StudentResult" come from?

Comment: you want to know every table that contains ModifiedTimeStamp?

Comment: select * from syscolumns...

Comment: @alleman yes only few tables have that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong,

What exactly You need is row count of each table containing column "ModifiedTimeStamp" right?

try this query...

```
-------------- find out tables containing column "MODIFIEDTIMESTAMP"-------------------
DROP TABLE #TMP1
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) ID, 
    TABLE_NAME 
INTO 
    #TMP1
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MODIFIEDTIMESTAMP%' 
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------loop each tables found, -------------------------------------
DECLARE @CNT INT = 1  ;
DECLARE @RN INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #TMP1)

IF @RN >1 
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='
IF OBJECT_ID(''TEMPDB.DBO.##TMP2'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TMP2
SELECT * INTO ##TMP2 FROM ('
WHILE @CNT <= @RN
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM #TMP1 WHERE ID=@CNT)
    SET @SQL = @SQL+ 'SELECT '''+ ISNULL(@TABLE_NAME,'') + ''' AS TABLE_NAME, YEAR(MODIFIEDTIMESTAMP) YEAR,COUNT(1) TOTAL_ROW FROM '+ ISNULL(@TABLE_NAME,'') +' WHERE MODIFIEDTIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL GROUP BY YEAR(MODIFIEDTIMESTAMP) 
UNION ALL
'
   SET @CNT = @CNT + 1;
END
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)-11) + ') Z'
PRINT @SQL
EXECUTE (@SQL)

SELECT * FROM ##TMP2
PIVOT(
    MAX(TOTAL_ROW)
    FOR YEAR IN([2016],[2017]) ---------you can make it dynamic by your self
)X

END
```

CMIIW,
Let me know if this useful...
Thanks

Comment: Perfect. it's working.thanks you

Comment: you're welcome :)